# Was Ursa a bender?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

(I haven't read the comics involving Ursa yet so as spoiler free as possible please)

She was granddaughter of the Avatar and mother to Azula and Zuko, both powerful benders but I don't recall if she's ever stated to be a bender or nonbender herself. Is this ever confirmed in the comics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not. Ursa is never shown to be capable of bending in any of her appearances in the animated series and the comics. It's true that she was descended from Avatar Roku, which was why she was chosen to marry Ozai, but the Avatar's descendants are not guaranteed to be benders. While two of Aang's children were benders, his son Bumi was not.

Comment: Bumi later could airbend after harmonic convergence.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can remember, Ursa never used any kind of bending in the comics, nor was it implied that she could do such a thing. *However*, she did carry some "bending genes", as seen in the *The Search* and *Smoke and Shadow* comic, where

> she had a third child, Kiyi, with the "commoner" Ikem (who's definitely not a firebender - he was attacked by firebenders and fought with swords). Kiyi was revealed in the third issue of *Smoke and Shadow* to be a firebender.
>  [image: Kiyi melting a steel door]
>  Obviously Zuko and Azula were benders too, but you could have argued that Ozai was a bender to begin with, so that could have stemed from here.

As the other answer mentions, though, obviously not all Avatar descendants are granted to be benders.